# Allowing subdomains through restrictions iPad 6th gen

Tags: ipad, parental-controls

I am trying to restrict access to websites on an iPad, but the domain that I wish to allow has embedded youtube videos that will not work. Is there a way to allow only the embedded videos to work, and not having to open up the entirety of youtube?

I tried allowing www.youtube.com/embed/ but that made youtube unrestricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title and body seem to be asking slightly different questions.

- Subdomains are distinct in restrictions. That is, `a.example.com` and `b.example.com` are distinct, and a restriction on one does not affect the other.

  Furthermore, subdomain restrictions override domain restrictions, such that if `example.com` is blocked but `a.example.com` is unblocked, then `a.example.com` will remain unblocked but `b.example.com` will be blocked.
- Paths (a.k.a. URL prefixes) are not distinct. That is, `example.com` and `example.com/a` are both regarded as `example.com`. It's not possible to use iOS restrictions to independently block or unblock just one of these.